# How to delete "The file name is too long." in windows. [Command Prompt]

Tags: windows, command-prompt, delete-file, robocopy

How to delete large file path/file name files in Windows.  Which is slimier to Linux rm -rf *.* ?

Comment: Ashish, while I laud your desire to increase the collective knowledge of StackOverflow, this is (due to its non-programming nature) probably more suited to SuperUser. So I (and a few others by the looks of it) are nudging it over to there.

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1263183/439537

Answer (score 34, accepted):

To delete **The file name is too long.** errors files, we've to go for simple steps using default command of Windows `robocopy` and `rmdir`.

1. Create directory `mkdir deleteLongFilesDir` under `C:` or `D:` drive
2. Suppose `D:\Development\Liferay\themes` directory contains the files which are not able to delete simply.
3. run command in command prompt `robocopy D:\deleteLongFilesDir D:\Development\Liferay\themes /purge` , this command will print some logs and copy you all the files and sub directory of `D:\Development\Liferay\themes` into `deleteLongFilesDir` folder virtually, but when you open that directory... hurreeee...**It's Empty ???**
4. Now run the command of remove directory which we created for mapping  `rmdir deleteLongFilesDir` from command line.
5. Now temporary directory has been deleted and same as for `D:\Development\Liferay\themes` files and folder.

Comment: This worked! Thanks!  I had a NetBeans Java build\classes directory with filenames containing nearly infinite number of repeated 'classes\build' in the paths.  This ran for about 10 minutes and showed no sign of stopping, so I Cntrl-C then re-ran the robocopy command and it completed in less than a minute.  After the rmdir command, all was well - empty classes directory!  After completion, my D: drive had 46 MB additional free space.  Weird.

Comment: Finally! I've never been that happy to see my files disappearing.

Comment: This worked like a charm. Great help. Thanks

Comment: This solution works and is correct, but the explanation is wrong. `robocopy` synchronizes the empty folder into to the target folder while purging the target folder (deleting files that are not present in the empty source, thus all).

Answer (score 1):

There is a Powershell cmdlet named **Remove-Item2**, written by Boe Prox a well-known MVP, and which circumvents the basic limitation path of 260 characters.

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Remove-LongPathFile-7a4db495

Additionally, like **Remove-Item2**, there are other cmdlets suffixed by the number 2, like **Get-ChildItem2**, which are often included in popular third party modules, and also addresses the 260 characters limitation. If you have installed some of these modules, there is a chance that you have already those cmdlets on your computer.